# How to calculate minimum excludant from graph for different permutation?

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, trees, python

This is practice problem in codechef. For complete [question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREEMX)

What I have done so far is, created a graph from list of tuples

(Ex: `input_list = [(1,2),(2,3)]`)

And taken all permutations for the set of `input_list`. Need to calculate **MEX** of each permutation and calculate length of distinct return values of `mex()` function.

```
# https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREEMX


from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations


class Graph:
    """ Graph is data structure(directed). """


    def __init__(self, connections):
        """ Initializing graph with set as default value. """
        self._graph = defaultdict(set)
        self.add_connections(connections)

    def add_connections(self, connections):
        """ Add connections(list of tupules) to graph. """
        for node1, node2 in connections:
            self.add(node1,node2)

    def add(self, node1, node2):
        """ Add node1 and node2 to graph which is initialized with set by default. """
        self._graph[node1].add(node2)
        self._graph[node2].add(node1)

    def get_graph(self):
        return dict(self._graph)


def mex(arr_set):
    mex = 0
    while mex in arr_set:
        mex+=1
    return mex


def process(graph, order):
    a_p = [0] * len(order)
    for i, el in zip(range(len(order)), order):
        a_p[i] = mex(graph[el])
    return a_p


t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    v = int(input())
    e = []
    for i in range(v-1):
        e.append(tuple(map(int, input().split())))

    g = Graph(e)
    print(g.get_graph())
    all_vertices = {s for i in e for s in i}
    result = []
    for p in permutations(all_vertices, v):
        out = process(g.get_graph(), p)
        print("{} --> {}".format(p, out))
        result.append(out) if out not in result else None

    print(len(result))
```

I'm struck at calculating in **MEX**.

Please explain how to complete that `mex` function (Please tell how to approach 
 or algorithm to implement that).

Any suggestion to my improve my code are welcome.

**Rules of problem:**

You have a tree $T$ with $n$ vertices. Consider an ordering $P=(v_1,…,v_n)$ of vertices of $T$. We construct a sequence $A(P)=(a_1,…,a_n)$ using the following process:

- Set all $a_i=−1$.
- Process vertices in order $v_1,…,v_n$. For the current vertex vi set
  $a_i=MEX(a_{u_1},…,a_{u_k})$, where $u_1,…,u_k$ is the set of
  neighbours of $v_i$.

**Unexpected results:**

```
1
3
1 2
2 3
{1: {2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2}}
(1, 2, 3) --> [0, 0, 0] # should be (0, 1, 0)
(1, 3, 2) --> [0, 0, 0]
(2, 1, 3) --> [0, 0, 0]
(2, 3, 1) --> [0, 0, 0] # should be (1, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 2) --> [0, 0, 0]
(3, 2, 1) --> [0, 0, 0]
1
```

Comment: Your `mex` function looks fine.  What's the problem?

Comment: @saulspatz Check now. I'm getting wrong `mex` value.

Comment: Whatever is wrong, it's not the mex function.; I just tested it.  This question would be more appropriate for stackoverflow.com, though.

Comment: @saulspatz, I have asked there. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349074/how-to-calculate-minimum-excludant-from-graph-for-different-permutation). Getting downvotes :( 

As this is a math topic. Some where in my code I'm missing it.Getting wrong output for mex function